# Why do Sefaradim skip "Uva LeTziyon" in the house of a mourner?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mourning-aveilus, shacharis-morning-prayer

This morning I prayed with a Sefaradi minyan in which were a few mourners. After *Hazarat HaSha"Tz*, they skipped *Tahhanun* and *Uva LeTziyon*.

I can imagine a justification for skipping Tahhanun; but, why do we skip Uva LeTziyon in the house of mourner?

Comment: Had the same question... I was told that its a minhag not halacha.

Answer (score 5):

A source for skipping a part of U'va L'tziyon in the house of a mourner is the Avudraham. [Avudraham - in Seder Tfilas H'taniyos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&st=&pgnum=134&hilite=) (end of page in this linked edition) says that similar to Tisha B'Av where we skip V'Ani Zos Brisi since we can not learn Torah then, the same should be done in the house of a mourner, since the mourner is forbidden to learn Torah.

> וכן בבית האבל נהגו שלא לאומרו מפני שגם כן האבל אסור לקרות בתורה

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct behaviour. The קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף brings down in        [סימן כט - סדר התפלות בבית האבל](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_65.html#HtmpReportNum0025_L2) that:

> **יז:** כשהקהל מתפללים בבית האבל אומרים פסוקי ''ובא לציון'' בשביל הציבור המתפלל עמהם. וכל שכן כשמתפללים בבית האבל במנחה של שבת, שאין לדלג הפסוקים ''ואני זאת בריתי'' וכו', כדי שלא להראות אבילות בפרהסיא בשבת, **ורק האבלים עצמם שמתפללים בלחש, ידלגו פסוקים אלה** גם בשבת. [ילקו''י אבלות מהדורת תשמ''ט עמוד קטו, ובמהדורת תשס''ד סי' כט עמ' תסד. יביע אומר חלק ד' דף שכ. חיו''ד סי' לב אות ז]‏

Basically, they always say the entire *Uva LeTziyon* - even in a mourner's house. Only the mourners - praying quietly - skip the first two verses.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question unless you can cite that this is the only valid opinion.

Comment: It's not the correct behavior for Shabbat, but is acceptable on a weekday.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Shulchan Aruch states to always so Uva Letzion. If some Sefardim had another custom, "Maran" would have mentioned it - and either approved or disapproved.

Comment: @147zcbm - sources, please.

Comment: The *Sha"Tz* was one of the mourners, so perhaps he was indeed acting in accordance with Maran HaRav Yosef Karo.

Comment: @Lee - Did they skip just 2 Pesukim or the entire Uva LTzion?

Comment: They acted in accordance with Siddur Kawanat HaLev, which states that "On Tish'ah Be'Av and in the house of a mourner, *mathhilim* from 'We'Atah Qadosh'".

Comment: @Lee - I think you should edit your question. Then I think I need to edit the answer (or delete it)